# Why "present simple" and not "simple present"?

Tags: grammar

When reading grammar, I find the names of the tenses kind of weird to me;

- **Present simple** and not **simple present**
- **past simple** and not **simple past**
- **present continuous** and not **continuous present**
- etc

Does this contradict with the "*adjective noun*" ordering rule or is it an exception (or something else)?

Comment: Just FYI, it is actually written both ways, e.g. http://www.google.com/search?q=%22simple+present%22

Comment: @Kosmonaut: isn't what I was alluding to in the last sentence of my answer?

Comment: @VonC: I'm sorry, you are right!  The last sentence of your answer somehow did not make it from my eyes to my brain.

Comment: It doesn't contradict the adjective noun ordering rule because simple and continuous are not nouns, they're adjectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think "present simple" or "past simple" contradict the "adjective noun" ordering rule;

You can consider "*present*" and "*past*" (the two morphologically distinct tense forms of the English tense system) as *qualifying* **[grammatical aspects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect)** (progressive or perfect).
Hence "*past* simple" or "*present* continuous".

But it is **more a usage** than a strict grammatical rule here:
Present simple can also be referred as "[Simple Present](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_simple)".

---

To rephrase the first part (about adjectives) a bit more clearly:

[The English Grammatical aspect Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect#English) mentions:
"The English tense-aspect system has two tenses, present and past, which are morphologically distinct."

My point is that **the tenses act as qualifier** (like adjectives do) for the grammatical aspects (same wikipedia entry: aspects beings "simple", "progressive", "perfect", ...).

So if the tenses are considered as adjectives, they are rightly placed in front of the aspects they qualify.

Comment: Would you please simplify a bit!

Comment: @Dia: I have reformulated my convoluted initial sentence. That will hopefully clarify it a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your "clarification", but I still need "simplification"! For example; what is "morphologically distinct tense" and what is "qualifying grammatical aspects"?

Comment: @Dia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect#English: "The English tense-aspect system has two tenses, present and past, which are morphologically distinct." My point is that the tenses act as qualifier (like adjectives do) the grammatical aspects (same wikipedia entry: aspects beings "simple", "progressive", "perfect", ...). So if the tenses are considered as adjectives, they are rightly placed in front of the aspects they qualify.

Comment: That's it! That's simplification, man! Thanks and +1

Comment: "Simple" is not an aspect. It's the lack of aspect. Or to be more literally, the lack of any auxiliary (in English, future simple is a notable example because of the modal auxiliary "will"); in this sense, it's the opposite of "compound/complex". Take the French "simple past" and "composed/complex past", for example: the former doesn't not require an auxiliary because the verbs themselves are self-sufficient, while the latter needs an auxiliary.

Answer (score 7):

My guess as to why there is variation is because Latin was the original language of education (among European languages).  In Latin, it would be natural to use the order "present simple".  With formal descriptions of English grammar that came later, some people translated these terms literally into English, retaining Latin word order, while others preferred to translate in a way that follows standard English order (as VonC said, both orders are used in English).  Also agreeing with VonC, I don't think it truly violates *adjective noun* ordering, only because it has crystalized as a set phrase — like an idiom.  People use the "present simple" order because it is (one version of) the name of this term.

I don't have a source on the history of Latin grammarians and their influence on English grammarians, so that is why I say it is a "guess", but if anyone does have a source, do let me know!

Comment: A good guess and sounds reasonable to me. And I add my voice to yours for any one that has a reference to let us know.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the reason "Present" was put before "Simple" is because that's the main concept, which is further extended by the adjectives "simple", "progressive" and "perfect". It's also easier to organize mentally as categories of tenses:

```
Present simple
Present progressive
Present perfect

Past simple
Past progressive
Past perfect
```

Someone then would naturally tend to see them as the 3 different forms of the "Present" tense, instead of the 3 different tenses of the "Simple" form as below:

```
Simple present
Simple past
Simple future

Progressive present
Progressive past
Progressive future
```

The latter doesn't emphasize the main categories which should be the tenses.

Answer (score -2):

**in simple present:**

Affrimative: Subject+Verb(s)
i/you/we/they  walk
he/she/it       walks

**Negative:** 
S+don't/Doesn't+infinitive

i/you/we/they  don't  walk
he/she/it      doesn't walk

**Interrogative Sentence:**
Do- I/you/we/they  walk?
Does- he/she/it    walk?

Answer (score -2):

In my humble point of view, and in brief; when we describe one of the perfect, continuous, or simple status we refer it to its concerned tense. Therefore, we consider our tense then as either a qualifier, or an adjective, which means that it must come first, though I prefer the form "Simple Present" rather than the other.
Best regards
Dr. Yasser Eltouny