# Why are English tense names backward (adjective after noun)?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, adjective-position, postpositive, attributive-adjectives

The adjectives in English tense names to often be [postpositive adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective): *present **continuous**/**progressive**/**perfect**(**ive**)*. *Simple* is used rather sloppily by different authorities, varying in either being postpositive in *present **simple***, and prepositive in ***simple** present*.

When it comes to French-origin adjectives, the tradition of using postpositive adjectives tend to be limited to a few longstanding institutions, like the military, the government, the monarchy, the judicial system, as exemplified by *court **martial***, *surgeon/secretary **general***, etc., which were imported into English under French-speaking Anglo-Norman rule.

But is there such longstanding tradition in grammar? When English grammar was first formally studied, did those first grammarians lift these postpositive adjectives straight out of French sources (or perhaps Latin sources)? What were the circumstances under which naming tenses with postpositive adjectives arose?

Comment: Here's my thought: in the 1600s and earlier, people rarely talked about English grammar, and much more commonly applied grammar to Latin. (People already knew how to speak English; they didn't need to write down grammar for it.) So if the adjectives were postpositive in Latin, they natural carried this over to English.

Comment: Here are some facts and opinions: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3220/349876

Comment: @PeterShor Exactly, though I'd love to know more about the background of the grammar tradition of English, preferable in the form of a good book. The French influence that brought us expressions like "court martial" is quite obvious: it was because of the protracted French rule, French was the elite, prestigious language in terms of government. For grammar, though, I'm not sure at all.

Comment: It is helpful when learning Romance languages, because the tense names are essentially the same, with spelling differences (present continuous -> présent continu).

Comment: "présent continu" is a direct translation from English, into French. That's why the tense names are "the same". English's borrowed lexicon heavily from French, no wonder their lexicons are similar. It's not really related to my question.

Comment: Of course the names didn't refer to the same tense constructions or meanings as they did in Latin or French. English, like all Germanic languages, lost all its I-E tenses except present and past long before the Common Era. The names borrowed from Latin didn't (and still don't) describe Modern English, which has either far fewer tenses or far more tenses, depending on [how many constructions one wants to call tenses](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/tense.html#tenselist).

Comment: @StuartF Not really, but I suppose it's basically the same question. The chosen answer answer's terrible. The most upvoted one, although being a conjecture I can make myself, qualifies as a satisfactory answer.